# React Native Can't Prompt pop-up to get Permission to get Camera Permission

Tags: react-native, android-camera, android-permissions, permission-denied

My code is:

```js
const handleButtonPress = async () => {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        title: 'Camera Permission',
        message: 'This app needs access to your camera to scan QR codes.',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
      },
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      setShowScanner(true);
      setScannedData('');
    } else {
      console.log('Camera permission denied');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
};
```

And I used a button to try to get permission to access to camera:

```js
TouchableOpacity style={{ padding: 10 }} onPress={handleButtonPress}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Scan QR Code</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I try to press the button to get the camera permission but it direct denied it without showing the pop-up.

I have added these lines in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```js
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

I try to uninstall and reinstall also cannot get the pop-up.
This caused me can't use the camera in my app.

Answer (score 0):

In Android To open camera on TouchableOpacity onPress when permission is granted like it asks user while using this App or only this time or Deny

OUTPUT:

[ask for Permission Pop up]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJcPz.png

enter image description here
Follow this steps:

open react-native project go to Explorer

```
android -> app -> src -> main -> open file AndroidManifest.xml
```

In AndroidManifest.xml file put this permission

```
<uses-permission
      android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
    />
```

the above permission allow for CAMERA access in adnroid

open Terminal and run this command to use device camera and access

```
npm install react-native-image-picker 
//or else you can do 
yarn add react-native-image-picker
```

also run this command for permissions it will install permission

```
npm install react-native-permissions
```

now create file and import this below line in it

```
  import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Image,
  Platform,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  PermissionsAndroid,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
    import {launchCamera} from 'react-native-image-picker';
    import {check, PERMISSIONS, RESULTS, request} from 'react-native-permissions';

    const CameraPermission = () => {

    const [imgUrl, setImgUri] = useState('');

  
      const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
        {
          title: 'Camera Permission',
          message:
            'App needs access to your camera ' + 'so you can take pictures.',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        },
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log('You can use the camera');
        opencamera();
      } else {
        console.log('Camera permission denied');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };

const opencamera = async () => {
    const result = await launchCamera();
    setImgUri(result?.assets[0]?.uri);
    console.log('RESULT>>>', result);
  };
return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      
//here you can see your clicked Image from camera
<Image
        source={{
          uri: imgUrl,
        }}
        style={{
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          alignSelf: 'center',
          borderRadius: 100,
          marginBottom: 20,
        }}></Image>

      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={requestCameraPermission}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: '#CE1C4F',
          paddingHorizontal: 20,
          marginHorizontal: 20,
          height: 40,
          borderRadius: 20,
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}>
        <Text
          style={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: '500',
            color: 'white',
          }}>
          Request Camera Permission
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>
  );
};
export default CameraPermission;
```

Happy Coding... :-)

Answer (score -1):

If a permission request is denied more than once, this is considered a permanent denial and the request is not prompted any more.

> If the user taps Deny for a specific permission more than once during your app's lifetime of installation on a device, the user doesn't see the system permissions dialog if your app requests that permission again.

Reset a state from settings:

*App info -> Permissions - Camera - Ask every time*

See [Permission dialog visibility](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions#dialog-visibility) for details.

Comment: In the setting, permissions part, it shows 'No permissions requested'.

Answer (score -1):

In your android/build.gradle make sure the minSdkVersion is >=23